# Efficient way of calculating most eigenvalues/eigenvectors, but not all

Tags: algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have done a larger literature study on algorithms for calculating the eigenvalues, and so far I have found no solution to the challenge. So
now I assume that the answer is very simple or intrinsic hard.

The problem is given generalized Hermitian eigenvalue problem: What is the most effective way to calculate a significant part of the eigenpairs (30%-60%).

From a complexity analysis point of view, all of the iterative solvers seems to require that the number of desired eigenvalues should be less than 10% or even smaller. For the QR family of eigenvalue algorithms it seems that none of them
has an effective way of calculating a part of the eigenvalue spectrum (and their associated eigenvectors)?

Anyone got any clues?

Edit:
Transforming it to an ordinary eigenvalue problem, does not answer the question,
as for a ordinary eigenvalue problem, the question is the same, as all algorithm gives you all or a few.

Comment: Given the generalized eigenvalue problem $Ax = \lambda B x$, is $B$ a positive definite matrix? If yes then this problem can be transformed to the standard symmetric eigenvalue problem for which there  are algorithms to find selected eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  All of the standard eigenvalue algorithm has the same properly that either you get all eigenpairs or a few.

Comment: No, you can compute selected eigenvalues for a symmetric eigenvalue problem, for example DSTEBZ from Lapack do this.

Comment: Okay, I will try this, but DSTEBZ only works on tridiagonal matrices and can't get the eigenstates?

Comment: You can compute eigenvectors using DSTEIN and reduce a symmetric matrix to tridiagonal matrix using DSYTRD. There are also driver routines DSYEVR, DSYEVX that do all required steps in one function call.

Comment: Thanks, you are right - I have tested it and it works quite well.